# Questions/answers reputation chart

Tags: feature-request, feedback

Sometimes I'm wondering if the particular user is more of an "asker" or the "answerer" type or how much of my reputation I built by asking questions. Would it be possible to add a chart that shows such information into the user profile?

Comment: You can see it by clicking on the user's profile (you see how many question/answers) as for how many point you made by asking question... [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A specific one, but not in total.

Comment: What do you mean *not in total* ?

Comment: What percentage of the user's reputation, since his/her registration, did he/she get by asking questions, what percentage by answering and what by other (if any).